# Cannot uninstall application with WiX

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, installation, wix

When I try delete my App1 via `Program and Components`, windows run `Uninstaller.exe` and my App1Uninstaller(WPF App) start, but, when i start Uninstall Process, App it asks to close that process, that is, Unistaller.exe asks close `Uninstaller.exe`.

I found some solution in thirdparty tools - copy this *.exe to Local/Temp/ and call it from there. But i don't know how to do it with WiX or with my program ?

Comment: @VladimirArustamian how logs will help there ? 
MSI has reference to uninstaller and it should delete it, but can't because its itself execute uninstall. As result uninstaller should run from other place (for example LocalTemp) but remove uninstaller by link from MSI.

Comment: You might want to add a bit more information about your App1 or rather its custom tailored WiX installation routine, which i assume you have.

Comment: Why do you need a custom program to do the uninstall?